# Hubbard model - Exact solution in infinite dimensions

Tags: condensed-matter

Can somebody tell me if there is some exact method which gives us the local self-energy of Hubbard model in the limit of infinite dimensions? If there is, where can I find it?

I found some diagrammatic perturbation theory, which leads us to that same solution in the limit of infinite dimensions, but when we use perturbation expansion, it is automatically an approximate method. What I else found is that the Green's function method to calculate self-energy also leads us to approximations because of the decoupling step, which is not trivial and is never exact.

If there isn't any procedure without approximations, why is it then called "the exact solution"?

Answer (score 1):

There is in fact a method that gives you a solution to the infinite dimensional Hubbard model, and this method is Dynamical Mean Field Theory (DMFT). This method is based on the assumption that the self energy does not depend on the lattice momentum $\vec{k}$, but only on an infinite set of discrete Matsubara frequencies $i\omega_n = (2n+1)\pi T$, where $n$ is an integer and $T$ the temperature. This assumption is in general not true for a general lattice, thus it's just an approximation, but it becomes true in the case of infinite dimensional lattices, so DMFT does not make approximations at all in this case (hence the name "exact").

Now the fact that there is an exact method to find the true self energy of the system does not mean we are actually able to solve it with a piece of paper and a pen: in fact we need computers and we can just obtain a numerical result to the problem. This of course introduces a degree of approximation due to the numerical approximations that we are forced to make. For example, we can't really compute the self energy on an infinite set of Matsubara frequencies, but just on a finite subset of them. Moreover, we need to introduce some thresholds to stop the code from running, and many other technical approximations to make things work properly.

To learn about DMFT you can start by checking out the dedicated Wikipedia page
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_mean-field_theory
and then there is a famous review by A. Georges and G. Kotliar written in 1996
https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.68.13 (this is very complete but also very technical).

So, philosophically, saying that the Hubbard model can be exactly solved in infinite dimensional lattices is just like saying that Newton's equations for the projectile motion in presence of air resistance can be exactly solved: we have very accurate equations of motion that describe the trajectory with (almost) no approximations, but this doesn't mean we can solve this equations analytically. However we can solve such equations within some numerical precision by using computers.